# How to make several img-wrappers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to display several images in img-wrapper divs. In the example below, there are 2 divs. But when I append an image to the second img-wrapper, it becomes shown not only in the second div as needed, but it appears over my first image. How to make several distinct images inside respective img-wrappers? My code uses a get http request to get second and later (a loop) image links. Thanks.

Here's my code:

view_topic.php

```
<div id="myDiv" class="img-wrapper"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
   
$('.img-wrapper').append($('<img id="theImg">').attr({
    'src': "https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/year-or-the-tank-girl-header.jpg" ,
    'alt': 'test image 1'
    })
).scrollTop(9999)
</script>

<div id="myDiv1" class="img-wrapper"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var get_a_image = "";

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    if (this.responseText != "no image")  {
        get_a_image = this.responseText;
    }
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "get_a_img.php?answer_id="+<?php echo $rows2_a_id; ?>+"&id="+<?php echo $id; ?>, false);
xhttp.send();
   
$('.img-wrapper').append($('<img id="theImg2">').attr({
    'src': get_a_image ,
    'alt': 'test image 2'
    })
).scrollTop(9999)
</script>
```

Comment: "when I append image to second img-wrapper" Nowhere are you doing this. You are appending to every element with the `img-wrapper` class. This is what `$(".img-wrapper")` does, it operates on all matched elements.

Comment: How to distict them?

Comment: Use the ID of the element

Comment: I am a newby, could you please provide an example?

Comment: Don't use . for class, use # for id. Also, see if you can make your code runnable here.  Don't worry if you can't get it running perfectly.  Just make an attempt and others can help you easier.  And don't reference images remotely.  Use placeholder images if necessary from a reputable source.